# how to detect touchesbegan touchesended for UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, touchesbegan

I am using an UIBarButtonItem in order to trigger events. I use the integrated InterfaceBuider in xcode4 to create my UIBarButtonItem and then I connected the button to a method in my view controller. The method looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)NoteOnOff:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

   /* now perform action */
}
```

Now I want to also detect fingerdown/fingerup because I want to trigger noteon/noteoff types of event for a midi synth kind of app.

1- Is there a way to detect if `sender` has been pressed down or up in the above method?

2- I tried to subclass UIBarButtonItem and implement touchesBegan and touchesEnded this way:

```
@interface myUIBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem {

}

@end

@implementation myUIBarButtonItem

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
NSLog(@"touches=%@,event=%@",touches,event);
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
NSLog(@"touches=%@,event=%@",touches,event);
}

@end
```

Then I changed the class of the UIBarButtonItem to myUIBarButtonItem in the interface editor but no luck. Is that the correct way of using my customized class in the interface editor?

3- I read somewhere that UIBarButtonItem does not inherit from UIResponder so they can't intercept touchesbegan/touchesended events. If that is the case then what is the proper way to be able to detect touches down and touches up events? I am mostly a C/C++ programmer and my knowledge is pretty limited about objective C and the iphone environement. I only know how to use the UI editor and I do not know how create custom UIs and use them without this editor yet.

Bottom line is: what is the simplest way to detect touchdown/touchup with the lest latency possible?

Any pointers to tutorial or docs is also welcome.

Thanks,

Baba

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it like this (no need to subclass UIBarButtonItem):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

- (void) touchUp:(id)sender {
}

- (void) touchDown:(id)sender {
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this looks like exactly what I need. One thing though is that i do not know how to access `button` since it was created in IB.

Comment: I tried to declare an IBOutlet in my viewcontroller.h this way: IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *myButton; then linking to that line of code from the IB, and then calling [myButton addTarget ....] in the viewdidload but I get runtime error that looks like this: -[UIBarButtonItem addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
*** Call stack at first throw:
What Am I Missing? thanks

Comment: That's because addTarget:action:forControlEvents: is declared in UIControl and UIBarButtonItem does not inherit from UIControl.